# Flutter JPEG2000 conversion

Tags: flutter, kotlin, jpeg2000, flutter-method-channel

I'm trying to read an e passport image data embedded on the chip using dmrtd , it's in Uint8List but I cant convert the data into an image

Ive been able to parse the image data and other information in it , from research it says Flutter doesn't support JPEG2000 out of the box , I've seen samples of apps in kotlin that are able to do this but I don't know kotlin and I have no idea on how to use method channels to do this, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

ive been able to do this , here a solution i made [here](https://github.com/ZeroPass/dmrtd/issues/9#issuecomment-1876064374)